# Get feed from page ordered by updated_time with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Since Facebook will deprecate FQL and I need to write a procedure that should get the latest updated post and comments I would opt for the 'me/feed' that gives me the possibility to search for a creation time window, but I need to order the result by last updates.

Is this possible? If someone puts a comment on a post created a long time ago I would like this post to be first in my Posts result from the feed, what is the recommend procedure without FQL?

Greetings, Tim

Comment: "Facebook will deprecate FQL" - can you please provide some evidence/link for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is No. The Graph API doesn't provide any such functionality as of now.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog As mentioned in link "FQL is still available in version 2.0, but will not be available in the next version of the API. This early warning is given so that developers can start migrating off FQL to the Graph API as soon as possible. We strongly recommend that developers build no new experiences based on FQL."

Comment: That's strange. I wonder what could be the reason behind this.